# Group by clause not giving expected result

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have two tables

- InvoiceHead(InvoiceID,RetailerID,ExecutiveID,InvoiceDate)
- InvoiceItem(InvoiceID,ItemID,Qty,Contract,Amount).

I want to get the sales qty grouped by ExecutiveId and ItemId.

I tried Following query but it doesn't give expected outcome.Grouping by both columns is not happening.As in the following screenshot the Same executive and item is not added together.they are in two rows

Screenshot of the result

[image]

```
SELECT 
    SecItem.ItemID
    ,SecHead.ExecutiveID
    ,sum(SecItem.QTY) AS Total_Qty
FROM Secondary_Sales.dbo.InvoiceHead AS SecHead
INNER JOIN Secondary_Sales.dbo.InvoiceItem AS SecItem 
    ON SecHead.InvoiceID = SecItem.Invoice_ID
GROUP BY 
    SecItem.ItemID
    ,SecHead.ExecutiveID
```

This query works in mysql and gives expected result but the same query doesn't work in msqlserver

Comment: what results do you get actually and what results do you want? show us a bit more information.

Comment: Because your problem is unclear, It would be great if you can setup http://sqlfiddle.com/ to show us the issue

Comment: I suggest you to do a sub query like (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM TableName) AS Quantity. That may solve the issue, I guess.

Comment: How about the relationship? Is it one to many between InvHead and InvItem? If yes you should be grouping it on [GROUP BY SecHead.ExecutiveID, SecItem.ItemID].

Comment: Try adding `+ '|'` to the end of both columns in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses, to see if one of them has trailing whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query as given should work, SQL Server does not implement things like this differently from MySql. I suspect this is a data issue. I suspect that the data for some of the IDs has trailing spaces. "GALSR02" does not equal "GALSR02 ". Try this query to see if that is the case:

```
SELECT 
    RTRIM(SecItem.ItemID)
    ,RTRIM(SecHead.ExecutiveID)
    ,sum(SecItem.QTY) AS Total_Qty
FROM Secondary_Sales.dbo.InvoiceHead AS SecHead
INNER JOIN Secondary_Sales.dbo.InvoiceItem AS SecItem 
    ON RTRIM(SecHead.InvoiceID) = RTRIM(SecItem.Invoice_ID)
GROUP BY 
    RTRIM(SecItem.ItemID)
    ,RTRIM(SecHead.ExecutiveID)
```

If that works then you will want to run this to correct the data and investigate how the white space got there in the first place. Once the data is corrected you can revert to your original query.

```
UPDATE Secondary_Sales.dbo.InvoiceHead
SET ExecutiveID = RTRIM(ExecutiveID), InvoiceID = RTRIM(InvoiceID)

UPDATE Secondary_Sales.dbo.InvoiceItem
SET ItemID = RTRIM(ItemID), Invoice_ID = RTRIM(Invoice_ID)
```

Comment: You are correct.I figured that.I imported some data from excel and some i entered manually.Imported data has some trailing spaces and that is why query didn't work. I corrected the data and now it works fine. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query..

```
;with cte_1
as 
(SELECT InvoiceID,ItemID,SUM(QTY)  OVER (partition by ItemID order by ItemID)New_QTY
FROM InvoiceItem )

SELECT c.ItemID,h.ExecutiveID,sum(c.New_QTY) AS Total_Qty
FROM Secondary_Sales.dbo.InvoiceHead  h
 JOIN cte_1 c
  on h.InvoiceID=c.InvoiceID
GROUP BY h.ExecutiveID,c.ItemID
```

if you wanted to pull the sum based on executiveId and item id, use the below query.

```
;with cte_1
as
(SELECT c.ItemID,h.ExecutiveID
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by  h.ExecutiveID,c.ItemID order by   h.ExecutiveID,c.ItemID) RNO
       ,SUM(QTY)  OVER (partition by   h.ExecutiveID,c.ItemID order by   h.ExecutiveID,c.ItemID) AS Total_Qty
FROM Secondary_Sales.dbo.InvoiceHead  h
 JOIN econdary_Sales.dbo.InvoiceItem c
  on h.InvoiceID=c.InvoiceID)
  SELECT ExecutiveID,ItemID,Total_Qty
  FROM cte_1
  WHERE RNO=1
```

Comment: That is if he's using SQL-Server 2008+

Comment: incorrect syntax near 'as' i'm using sql server 2016

Comment: Sum is only grouped with item and that qty is displayed with all other executives who are having that same item

Comment: that query also failed.I tried my query which was in the question in mysql using same db structure and it gave the expected result but the same query doesn't give the result in sql server

Answer (score -1):

Try with below query hope it helps .

```
SELECT SecItem.ItemID,SecHead.ExecutiveID,sum(SecItem.QTY) AS Total_Qty
FROM Secondary_Sales.dbo.InvoiceHead AS SecHead
INNER JOIN Secondary_Sales.dbo.InvoiceItem AS SecItem ON SecHead.InvoiceID = SecItem.Invoice_ID
GROUP BY SecItem.ItemID,SecHead.ExecutiveID,SecItem.QTY
```

Comment: Makes no sense to put SecItem.QTY in the GROUP BY clause... The rule is either argument to aggregate function OR listed in the GROUP BY.